# Fetching all columns of Inner Join

Tags: php, inner-join

I need to fetch all the columns in the two tables. But i cant seem to fetch the data is there anything wrong with my php or is it my javascript.

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

include("global.php");

$conn = new mysqli(server, dbuser, dbpw, db);
$userid = $_GET['userid'];

$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM profiles INNER JOIN StudentProfile ON profiles.userid = StudentProfile.userid");

$outp = "[";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "[") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '{"userid":"'  . $rs["userid"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"parentname":"' . $rs["parentname"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"profilepic":"' . $rs["profilepic"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"contact":"' . $rs["contact"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"address":"' . $rs["address"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"studentid":"' . $rs["studentid"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"studentname":"' . $rs["studentname"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"sclass":"'   . $rs["sclass"]        . '"}';
    $outp .= '"sprofilepic":"' . $rs["sprofilepic"] . '",';
}
$outp .="]";



$conn->close();

echo($outp);
?>
```

[studentprofile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceeAv.png)
[profiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVKki.png)

Comment: Show your tables. Also, use this http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: @bassxzero tables are added

Answer (score 0):

### 1. you can do it with [fetch_all](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php). for this you must have [mysqlnd](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php) driver

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM profiles INNER JOIN StudentProfile ON profiles.userid = StudentProfile.userid");

$output = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$jsonOutput = json_encode($output);
```

### 2. with loop

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM profiles INNER JOIN StudentProfile ON profiles.userid = StudentProfile.userid");

$output = [];
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $output[] = $rs;
}
$jsonOutput = json_encode($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your JavaScript in your code ...

check out last 2 lines of code inside while loop

just replace

> $outp .= '"sclass":"'   . $rs["sclass"]        . '"}';
>
> $outp .= '"sprofilepic":"' . $rs["sprofilepic"] . '",';

With

> $outp .= '"sclass":"'   . $rs["sclass"]        . '",';
>
> $outp .= '"sprofilepic":"' . $rs["sprofilepic"] . '"},';

Comment: isit okay if i use the array with the inner join @kunal